# Data sim and set.seed()

Tags: r

I've been assigned to create a dataset of simulated patient data in R for an assignment. We've been provided variable names and thats it. I want to be able to get a random sample of 100, and use set.seed() to make it reproducible, but when I run the code, I originally got different sample variables each time I re-open the script, and now it I just get error messages and it won't run

This is what I have:

```
pulse_data <- data.frame(
                    group = c(rep("control", "treatment")),
                    age = sample(c(20:75)),
                    gender = c(rep("male", "female")),
                    resting_pulse = sample(c(40:120)),
                    height_cm = sample(c(140:220))
                    )
  
set.seed(30)
pulse_sim <- sample_n(pulse_data, 100, replace = FALSE)
```

am I missing something fundamental?!

(total beginner, speak to me like an idiot and I might understand :) )

I've tried to sample_n() straight from the dataframe, with the set.seed() and to put set.seed() inside the pulse_sim but to no avail... as for why I get errors now, I'm at my wits end

Comment: I worked out the error and corrected it [ the rep(c("control", "treatment") has the rep and c the wrong way round] but the set.seed() issue still refuses to work

Answer (score 0):

Realize that `pulse_data` is created using random data, so each time the script is called, you get random data. After you create it, you set the random seed, so you get the same rows you did the last time you opened the script, but ... the rows have different data. **SOLUTION**: set the random seed *before* you define `pulse_data`.

```r
pulse_data <- data.frame(
                    group = rep(c("control", "treatment"), length.out=30),
                    age = sample(c(20:75), size=30),
                    gender = rep(c("male", "female"), length.out=30),
                    resting_pulse = sample(c(40:120), size=30),
                    height_cm = sample(c(140:220), size=30)
                    )

pulse_sim <- sample_n(pulse_data, 10, replace = FALSE)
```

I have put that code, plus a simple `pulse_sim` again (to print it) in a file `74408236.R`. (Note that I added `length.out` and changed your sample size from 100 to 10, for the sake of this demonstration.) I can run this briefly with this shell command (*not in R*):

```bash
$ Rscript.exe 74408236.R
       group age gender resting_pulse height_cm
1  treatment  28 female            76       210
2  treatment  24 female           118       140
3    control  44   male            57       141
4    control  70   male            96       184
5  treatment  22 female            87       177
6    control  30   male            50       168
7    control  39   male            56       145
8  treatment  37 female           120       182
9  treatment  20 female            79       181
10 treatment  75 female            98       186
```

When I run it a few times in a row, I get the same output. For brevity, I'll demonstrate same-ness by showing its MD5 checksum; while MD5 is not the most "secure" (cryptographically), I think this is an easy way to suggest that the output is unlikely to be different. (This is shell-scripting, still *not in R*.)

```bash
$ for rep in $(seq 1 5) ; do Rscript.exe 74408236.R | md5sum; done
0f06ecd84c1b65d6d5e4ee36dea76add  -
0f06ecd84c1b65d6d5e4ee36dea76add  -
0f06ecd84c1b65d6d5e4ee36dea76add  -
0f06ecd84c1b65d6d5e4ee36dea76add  -
0f06ecd84c1b65d6d5e4ee36dea76add  -
```

In fact, if I repeat it 100 times, I still see no change. I'll pipe through `uniq -c` to replace repeated output with the count (first number) and the output (everything else, the checksum).

```bash
$ for rep in $(seq 1 100) ; do /mnt/c/R/R-4.1.2/bin/Rscript.exe 74408236.R | md5sum; done | uniq -c
    100 0f06ecd84c1b65d6d5e4ee36dea76add  -
```

Comment: I tried again, and each time I am still getting a different sample of 100...

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. When I run this (whole) code repeatedly, I always get the same numbers. If you call `set.seed` then create `pulse_data`, it should always be then same thing. If you then pull the table sample, it should be the same as your previous FIRST random sample. If you pull another random sample, it will be different. If you repeat any portion of the code above, ANY portion repeated, you will change your results.

Comment: When I run the whole code repeatedly I also get the same numbers, but if I close the script and re-open it and then re-run, I get different numbers, and this means the statistical test I run on the data gets a different result each time.

Comment: Sarah, see my edits. I suspect that you are doing something not in the original code, nor in my answer, and therefore something else is changing your output.

Comment: Thanks - I changed the replace = FALSE to replace = TRUE and that seemed to solve it. Much appreciated